# NTLM Authentication not possible in AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm writing an App Engine application that interfaces with a
corporate SharePoint Server that needs to authenticate using [NTLM
Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc207842.aspx) (no support for Basic,Digest or Kerberos auth)

I'm using Apache [HttpClient 4.1.3](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) because it supports NTLM
authentication out of the box.

You need to implement a custom [ClientConnectionManager](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/ClientConnectionManager.html) and
[ManagedClientConnection](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/ManagedClientConnection.html) because some of the classes used internally
are not in the [AppEngine JRE Class White List](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist.html), but found a couple of
implementations in internet so no probs there ([ESXX Server](http://esxx.org/) implements one).

I eventually have it working on my local AppEngine Development server
but to my surprise it won't work on the production AppEngine server.

After many investigations, I found that **NTLM Authentication needs a
persistent connection** in order to make a handshake consisting in
exchanging 3 messages in 2 consecutive HTTP requests. Those 2 HTTP requests **MUST**
be done using the same connection (persistent connection), if not the
server will refuse to authenticate.

It seems the **URLFetchService uses different connections for each
request** and there is no way of keeping the connection open. The same
applies if you're using a URLConnection ... as soon as you receive a
response you cannot send more data up in that connection.

Does anybody have managed to do NTLM authentication in AppEngine?

Is there anyway to have a persistent connection?

*I'm using AppEngine version 1.6.3.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're out of luck on this one.  App Engine does not support persistent HTTP connections.
reference at the bottom here: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/usingjavanet.html

The only way I know of to create a persistent connection on App Engine is via the Channel API, and that's only for creating a channel, you have no access to the underlying TCP connection.

Comment: Thanks dragonx, that's what I was afraid of. I posted this question too wishing somebody from AppEngine team gave some insight if there is any plan on improving the URLFetchService with persistent connections.

Comment: I doubt it, but it doesn't hurt to put in a feature request.  The GAE design seems to be about scalability, where any HTTP request can be routed to any instance, and instances can come up and go down almost arbitrarily.  The whole concept of having a persistent connection in this case goes against the design.

Thinking a bit more, backends are designed to be somewhat persistent, so it should be possible for an HTTP request from a backend to be persistent, but I don't see any API for such a feature.

Comment: Somebody already submitted a feature request. Posting the link here: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=5073