# Ntlm authentication Google apppengine java

Tags: google-app-engine

How to write **ntlm** authentication in **google appengine java?** Is it supported in GAE JAVA.  Actually i want to connect to the share point server from the google appengine java project. But the share pont server needs **NTLM** Authntication.

Comment: This question is too broad and others might put it on hold.  On StackOverflow you are expected to do your own research and try to implement something by yourself, and then post questions here about details of your code that need help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NTLM Authentication not possible in AppEngine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623420/ntlm-authentication-not-possible-in-appengine)

Comment: I have seen that question But that question is 2 years ago. After that appengine got released latest versions. Right now is it supported or not.In that question there is no solution to how to achieve in appengine.